# Is it possible to replace the local planner in the default ROS Navigation stack to one that uses reinforcement learning?

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, dwa-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building a driverless car and the current problem is the TEB Local Planner.

I was wondering if it is possible to replace with an RL agent, and whether this has been done before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261750/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-local-planner-in-the-default-ros-navigation-stack-to-one-that-uses-reinforcement-learning?/) by [Azzu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30387/azzu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-08**:
have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Definitely possible. You will need to implement a "base local planner plugin" of `nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner` . You can follow this tutorial to create a plugin (http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin).

The `nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner` class has a few pure virtual function so you will have to re-implement them, but basically you just need to implement your planner in the function `computeVelocityCommands`.

You can also access the costmap_2d object (which is given by the `initialize` function) so you can perform any logic/algorithm  to detect/avoid obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1